# Spring Boot does not create the Restful WS when we give @RequestBody or @RequestHeader as a method parameter

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, annotations

In our project we have a Interface and an Implementing Class
In the interface we provide all method signature that is annotated with @RequestMapping annotation. The class that is implementing this interface is annotated with @RestController and @RequestMapping annotations and overriding all the methods in that interface.

**Issue:** In any of the methods, When i give @RequestBody or @RequestHeader as parameter, Spring boot is not even creating the /v1/myapi/load URL given in the @RequestMapping in the interface. But if i give just empty parameters its creating the URL.

Further digging in, i also figured out that if i remove the @RequestMapping annotations from the interface methods and provide it in the methods in controller class its working irrespective of giving anything in the method parameter.

I just want to know why the @RequestMapping provided in the interface is not considered when we use @RequestBody or @RequestHeader as a method parameter.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v1/myapi/")
public class MyControllerClass implements MyInterface{
@Override
public ResponseObject method1(@RequestBody String request,  @RequestHeader(name= HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String token){

}

//Interface Class
public interface MyInterface {
      @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value="/load",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
ResponseObject method1(@RequestBody String request, @RequestHeader(name= HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String token) throws Exception;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The annotations must all be in either the implementing class *or* in the controller interface (if you choose to have one) in order to work correctly. Copied from the JavaDoc of [@RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html):

> **NOTE:** When using controller interfaces (e.g. for AOP proxying), make sure to consistently put *all* your mapping annotations - such as @RequestMapping and @SessionAttributes - on the controller *interface* rather than on the implementation class.

Comment: Thanks for the pointing. Now it makes sense and i am able to see all my RequestMapping getting created regardless of method parameters in it.